# Proving a jacobian matrix is symmetric

Tags: matrices

I am following this [tutorial](https://mattpetersen.github.io/softmax-with-cross-entropy) and in it they make a statement that the jacobian is symmetric. So, I have $\partial f(\mathbf{x}) / \partial {x}$, and I want to mathematically prove that it is symmetric. Here, $f(\mathbf{x})$ is softmax function.

I know that $f(\mathbf{x}) = f(\mathbf{x})^T$ must be satisfied to prove that two matrices are symmetric. However, I'm not sure how to mathematically begin doing this. Should I be re-deriving softmax in a different way to incorporate the "transposed" portion of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The off-diagonal $i,j$ entries of the Jacobian in *this specific case* are
$$
-s_i(\mathbf x)s_j(\mathbf x)
$$
as mentioned in the paragraph just before where they state that the Jacobian is symmetric. This is clearly equal to
$$
-s_j(\mathbf x)s_i(\mathbf x)
$$
showing that the Jacobian *in this specific case* is symmetric.

In general, Jacobian matrices (even square ones) are not symmetric.

Comment: Ahh, I see, that was actually a simple and straightforward way, thank you